# Use HeaderedItemsControl in Datagridcell not showing Content

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I want to disply a `HeaderedItemsControl`in a `DataGridTemplateColumn`. However, the following code only shows the header, but not the content. Where did I go wrong?

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <HeaderedItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Days[0].Employee}">
            <HeaderedItemsControl.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="HeaderedItemsControl">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Employee"/>
                        <Button Grid.Column="1"></Button>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </HeaderedItemsControl.Template>
            <HeaderedItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </HeaderedItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <HeaderedItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </HeaderedItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </HeaderedItemsControl>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to include `ItemsPresenter` in your Template. So your control has only header, nothing else. Just adding it back will do the trick:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="HeaderedItemsControl">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="22" />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Employee" />
        <Button Grid.Column="1" />

        <ItemsPresenter Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Also, are you sure `Days[0].Employee` is a collection? It looks strange for sure.

---

As a bonus, you don't really have to use `HeaderedItemsTemplate`. Your template is simple enough to make it with basic controls:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="24" />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Text="Employee" />
                <Button Grid.Column="1" />

                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Days[0].Employee}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                     <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you. The Bonus works very nice! Btw: Yes, Days[0].Employee is a collection. I usually translate the object/collection names, but made a little mistake translating;)

Comment: @Mister832, glad it helped. Cheers!